# Difference between css3 transition and jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have previously used transitions to increase,decrease the width of a div and also changed the background color of a div to get a animation type of effect. I have also done these same things by using animate function in jQuery. The effect  that I  got by using these two processes are the same. If anyone could help me with the difference between them that would be helpful. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you inspected the core jQuery code for `.animate()`? Have you researched what happens when using CSS3 animations / transitions?

Comment: Read a book broda

Comment: I didn't  inspect the code, I never thought that the difference would be in the core code. Thanks for the suggestion. I will check the difference in code by inspecting the code with these two  methods. @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Can you suggest me a good one? @claudios

Comment: If you could just use [Google](https://www.google.cz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css3%20transitions%20vs%20jquery%20animation) instead of Stackoverflow. You would be surprised and get a lot of relevant results.

Comment: @user3663922, google it or check it out here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/css-vs-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the reference @claudios